# axis2 causing javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: element text content may not contain START_ELEMENT

Tags: java, xml, apache-axis

I generated an axis2 web service client through eclipse.

I'm always having this error on execution.

`org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: element text content may not contain START_ELEMENT`

in the wsdl I have

```
<xsd:element name="transactionError" type="transactionError"/>
<xsd:complexType name="transactionError">
<xsd:all>
<xsd:element name="request_id" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="trans_id" nillable="true" type="string"/>
<xsd:element name="date_time" nillable="true" type="string"/>
<xsd:element name="error_code" nillable="true" type="int"/>
<xsd:element name="error_text" nillable="true" type="string"/>
</xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
```

And on debugging the call i can see the response is

```
<n:transactionError xmlns:n="http://www.xxxx.com/wsdl/xxxxx.wsdl">
<transactionError>
<request_id>Rxxxxxx</request_id>
<date_time>2016-02-06 12:02:53</date_time>
<error_code>-12</error_code>
<error_text>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</error_text>
</transactionError></n:transactionError>
```

On `java.lang.String content = reader.getElementText();`

it is throwing the exception 
`javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: element text content may not contain START_ELEMENT`

on reader with these properties  :

`reader.currentNode = <transactionError><request_id>Rxxxxxx</request_id><date_time>2016-02-06 12:02:53</date_time><error_code>-12</error_code><error_text>xxxxxxxxx</error_text></transactionError>`

`reader.namespaceCount = -1`

Any idea what can the problem be ?

Comment: Do the `<error_text>` or `<request_id>` tags contain unescaped `<` symbol inside them? (`<` in text content and attribute values must be escaped as `&lt;`)

Comment: No the values are plain text Rxxxxxx with x a number, and error text a simple text

Answer (score 5):

You can only call the [XMLStreamReader.getElementText()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#getElementText--) method on elements which contain text-only content. It would be okay to call this method for `<request_id>`, `<date_time>`, `<error_code>` or `<error_text>` since the children of those elements are only text, but you cannot use this method on `<transactionError>` since it has other elements as children.

The Javadoc for [XMLStreamReader.getElementText()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#getElementText--) contains detailed pseudocode which shows how the method computes the `String` that it returns and under what conditions it will throw an `XMLStreamException`. If the current element has any element children this method will throw an exception.

If Axis2 generated this code I would suggest checking whether they've fixed this in a more recent version and opening a [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel) against their project in Apache if it's still an issue.